# On Rebuild Application_start -> Application_End -> Application_Start is fired

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC Application when I rebuild the Application the Application's events are getting 
fired in the following order.

Application_start
Application_End
Application_Start

I am not doing any changes to my Web.config..
Also I checked and found that my Application pool is not recycled.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any Pre-build and/or Post-build events configured in VS.

Comment: Thanks Malkam, but I dont have any Pre-build or Post-buid events configured in VS